# Metacharacters and parenthesis in regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone elaborate/translate this regular expression into English?

Thank you.

```
var g = "123456".match(/(.)(.)/);
```

I have noticed that the output looks like this:

```
12,1,2
```

and I know that dot means any character except new line. But what does this actually do?

Comment: I don't know, but it's making me nervous and sweaty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pair of parenthesis (without a ? as the first character, indicating other behaviour) will capture the contents to a group.

In your example, the first item in the array is the entire match, and subsequent items are any group matches.

It might be clearer if your code was something like:

```
var g = "123456".match(/.(.).(.)./);
```

This will match five characters, placing the second and fourth into groups 1 and 2 respectively, so outputting `12345,2,4`

If you want pure grouping without capturing the content, use `(?:...)` syntax, the `?:` part indicating a non-capturing group. (There are various assorted group things, like lookaheads and other [fun stuff](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html).)

Let me know if that is clear, or would further explanation help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks for two characters - any characters because of the dots - and 'captures' them so that you can look for the whole string that was matched, and for each of the substrings (captures) as well.